# Configuring mybatis to skip JDBC failures caused by /*... */ style comments in SQL scripts

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, mybatis, wikipedia

I'm trying to load the Wikipedia dumps (for example, [this one](https://dumps.wikimedia.your.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-category.sql.gz)), which are a series of .sql scripts, into an SQLite database via the org.xerial sqlite-jdbc connector and MyBatis, but it appears to be failing on some /* ... */ style comments at the beginning of the file with the following error:

```
 org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.RuntimeSqlException: Error executing: /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */
.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver
    at org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.ScriptRunner.executeLineByLine(ScriptRunner.java:159)
    at org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.ScriptRunner.runScript(ScriptRunner.java:119)
    at com.tracesemantics.knowledgeengine.DatabaseConnector.loadSQLFile(DatabaseConnector.java:120)
    at com.tracesemantics.knowledgeengine.DatabaseConnector.loadSQLFiles(DatabaseConnector.java:67)
    at com.tracesemantics.knowledgeengine.KnowledgeEngine.loadWikimediaDumpsIntoDatabase(KnowledgeEngine.java:155)
    at com.tracesemantics.knowledgeengine.KnowledgeEngine.call(KnowledgeEngine.java:119)
    at com.tracesemantics.knowledgeengine.KnowledgeEngine.call(KnowledgeEngine.java:1)
    at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:1933)
    at picocli.CommandLine.access$1200(CommandLine.java:145)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2332)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2326)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2291)
    at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2159)
    at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2058)
    at com.tracesemantics.knowledgeengine.KnowledgeEngine.main(KnowledgeEngine.java:93)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.unused(JDBC3Statement.java:387)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.setEscapeProcessing(JDBC3Statement.java:382)
    at org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.ScriptRunner.executeStatement(ScriptRunner.java:243)
    at org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.ScriptRunner.handleLine(ScriptRunner.java:223)
    at org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.ScriptRunner.executeLineByLine(ScriptRunner.java:152)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

The start of the input file is:

```
    -- MySQL dump 10.16  Distrib 10.1.45-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
    --
    -- Host: 10.64.48.13    Database: enwiki
    -- ------------------------------------------------------
    -- Server version       10.1.43-MariaDB
    
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
    /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
    /*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
    /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
    /*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
    /*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
    /*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

I think these comments are intended to give instructions to MySQL databases. Given that they're not supported by SQLite, is there any way I can configure either the JDBC driver or MyBatis to ignore these comments so that I can get the data into the database?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Judging by the stacktrace, the exception has nothing to do with those comments, the script runner attempts to call setEscapeProcessing on the statement, and the SQLite driver hasn't implemented this (which BTW is a violation of the JDBC specification).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ah well spotted - I didn't see that. Interesting to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you also know about comment like this "/* ... bla bla ... */".

That must do not work on your mind, but it works.

Thus, I recommend you that change the comment from "/*... */" to "-- bla bla".
start of "--" comment can ignore that line without run.

ex>
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
=>
-- 40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT

Answer (score 0):

Oh, found a solution...

```java
scriptRunner.setEscapeProcessing(false);
```